# Let $f:V \to V$ be Endomorphism of vector space $V$ and $v\in V$ such that for $n\in \mathbb{N}:f^n(v)\neq 0\text{ and } f^{n+1}(v)=0$. Linear indepen

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces, vectors

Let $f: V \to V$ be an Endomorphism of the vector space $V$ and $v \in V$, such that for $n \in \mathbb{N}$:
$$f^n(v) \neq 0 \text{ and } f^{n+1}(v) = 0$$

Here $f^n(v)$ means, that the map $f$ is applied $n$ times on the vector $v$. Prove that $v, f(v), ..., f^n(v)$ are linearly independent.

---

To show they are linearly independent, we must have that
$$a_0v + a_1f(v) + ... + a_nf^n(v) = 0$$
implies that $a_0 = a_1 = ... = a_n = 0$

We apply $f$ once and get
$$a_0f(v) + a_1f^2(v) + ... + a_{n-1}f^n(v) + a_nf^{n+1}(v) = 0$$

We know $f^{n+1}(v) = 0$, so we are left with
$$a_0f(v) + a_1f^2(v) + ... + a_{n-1}f^n(v) = 0$$

If we apply $f$ enough time, we are left with $a_0f^n(v) = 0 \implies a_0 = 0$

Is this correct until now ? But what do I do now ? Doesn't this only hold for $a_0$ ?

And why do we need an Endomorphism ? It seems to me this isn't needed

Comment: Since $a_0=0$,$$0=a_0+a_1f(v)+\cdots+a_nf^n(v)=a_1f(v)+a_2f^2(v)+\cdots+a_nf^n(v).$$So, you start all over again and you prove that $a_1=0$ and so on.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos But why does it need to be an endomorphism ?

Comment: What's your definition of endomorphism?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The one from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism Or do they just write it because $f$ maps from $V$ to $V$ itself ? It just seems superfluous for me, but anyway. I thought the question requires using some properties of endomorphism, otherwise they wouldn't write it

Comment: If $f$ was *not* an endomorphism of $V$, that is, if $f$ was a map from some vector space $V$ into some *other* vector space $W$, then, in general, $f^2$ would not make sense, right?!